# How do I make a sum matching two IDs located in different rows - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

| id | parentid | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79648627 | 79648626 | 1 |
| 79648626 | null | 2 |

Current Table, I want to match the parentid with the id and in case they match get the same value of the amount where the parentid is null, in other words desired result:

| id | parentid | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79648627 | 79648626 | 2 |
| 79648626 | null | 2 |

Comment: Sum what?  I see nothing where the sum is 2.  `2 + 1 = 3`.

Comment: also is it only one level parent or you want go all way down?

Comment: I want to match the parentid with the id
parentid 79648626 = id 79648626 and then counts the same value of the amount or 2 and given that the row is null leave the amount  as it is or 2.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the script that you have tried so far regarding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one level of hierarchy then you can use subquery to get your result.

```
 create table testtable(id int,  parentid int,  amount int);
 insert into testtable values(79648627, 79648626,   1);
 insert into testtable values(79648626, null,       2);
```

Query:

```
 select id,parentid, 
 (case when parentid is not null then (select amount from testtable tt where tt.id=t.parentid) else amount end )amount
 from testtable t
```

Output:

| id | parentid | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 79648627 | 79648626 | 2 |
| 79648626 | null | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=14438bf85b4efd908be278f94bf702c6)*

Comment: It shows me that the value of the first row is null not 2. 
The logic seems to have an error.

Comment: Please check the db-fiddle link. And please share your code which is returning null.

Comment: There is an error. instead of tt.id=tt.parentid please use tt.id=t.parentid.